# equivalent of ave() in tidyverse ecosystem

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I was wondering what would be the equivalent of `cov(sapply(dat[-1], ave, dat[1]))` in `library(tidyverse)` in my code below?

```
library(tidyverse)

(T1 = matrix(c(2,3,5,2, 3,4,4,5),4,2)  )      
colnames(T1) <- c("y1", "y2")

(T2 = matrix(c(4:6, 8,6,7),3,2)  )      
colnames(T2) <- colnames(T1) 

(T3 = matrix(c(7,8,10,9,7, 6,7,8,5,6),5,2)  )      
colnames(T3) <- colnames(T1) 

(dat <- map_df(list(T1,T2,T3), as_tibble, .id = 'group'))

cov(sapply(dat[-1], ave, dat[1])) # equivalent of this in tidyverse

#         y1       y2
#y1 5.624242 2.218182
#y2 2.218182 1.731818
```

Comment: how about: `dat %>% group_by(group) %>% transmute_all(mean) %>% ungroup() %>% 
 select(-group) %>% cov()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `ave` within `map`, convert to data.frame with `_dfc` ie. binding columnwise and then apply the `cov`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfc(dat[-1], ave, dat[1]) %>%
    cov
#         y1       y2
# y1 5.624242 2.218182 
# y2 2.218182 1.731818
```

---

Or an option with `mutate_all`

```
dat %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   mutate_all(mean) %>% 
   ungroup %>%
   select(-group) %>%
   cov
```

---

With the updated comment about applying `reduce`

```
dat %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(new = list(cov(cur_data()) * (n() - 1)),
         .groups = 'drop') %>%
   pull(new) %>% 
   reduce(`+`)
#    y1  y2
#y1 14.8 1.6
#y2  1.6 9.2
```

Comment: Akrun, is it possible to simplify this one also, `(Ws = group_split(dat, group, .keep = FALSE) %>%
  map(~ cov(.) * (nrow(.) - 1)));  (pooled_W = Reduce('+', Ws))`

Comment: @rnorouzian yes, we could.  Can you also check the other post where I did a simplification of your conditions

Comment: @rnorouzian I meant in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66202448/combine-two-looping-structures-to-obtain-a-matrix-output). If you check the output, there are two Reduce conditions, which you are doing similar operations and I simplified it

Comment: @rnorouzian It is a single chain process.  In your code, it is doing the same operation twice.

Comment: @rnorouzian how about `dat %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(new = list(cov(cur_data()) * (n() - 1)), .groups = 'drop') %>% pull(new) %>% reduce(`+`)`

Comment: Appreciate it a lot, I think I will keep my initial code. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One option could be:

```
dat %>%
 group_by(across(1)) %>%
 mutate(across(everything(), mean)) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 select(-1) %>%
 cov()

         y1       y2
y1 5.624242 2.218182
y2 2.218182 1.731818
```